# How to allow users to view pending posts of a specific custom post type?

Tags: filters, user-roles

I have a form on the front end that allows users to post a custom post type. The posts enters the database as **pending** for later moderation, how do I allow users to view these posts on the front end? Currently I get a 404 because it is in pending status, but in this case it is okay to display the post.

Comment: show us the code which create the CPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a custom query to display these pending posts. Here is an example using `get_posts()`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post_type_name',
    'post_status' => 'pending',
    // -1 shows all
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$pending_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $pending_posts as $pending_post ) {
    // post object properties
    $id = $pending_post->ID;
    $title = $pending_post->post_title;
    $content = $pending_post->post_content;

    // output
    echo $id;
    echo $title;
    echo $content;
}
```

If you need to filter an existing query instead of making a new one (for example, on an archive page), you should use [`pre_get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Comment: Perfect solution mate! Thanks so much! This is what makes this community is great. And I was messing with the ugly filter `user_has_cap` and got nothing... your solution is much better, clever and safe. I ended up using the filter `pre_get_posts` and then setting `$query->set( 'post_status', array('pending', 'publish' ) );`, it worked like a charm.